# Using Entity Framework 4.1 with SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, entity-framework-4.1

First, I am not completely familiar with SharePoint development. I have been tasked to build an application with it.

I need some advice on using entity framework 4.1 with SharePoint. I have some code already written that makes use of EF 4.1 and the repository pattern (which I don’t want to give up). I want to have control over my data model and allow the SP applications to take care of workflow and document management.

What is the best approach to using these together? I have read about creating a web service layer that SP will communicate with. I am hoping there are some resources out there that I couldn’t find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is based on the .NET FrameWork 3.5, which requries IIS to use the ASP.NET 2.0 Runtime. Entity Framework 4.1 uses the .NET FrameWork 4.0, which requries IIS to use the ASP.NET 4.0 runtime. As a result you cannot run EF 4.1 natively in SharePoint 2010. What you can do is use web services as you mentioned in your question to wrap your EF 4.1 objects.

Other options are to have a Silverlight hosted application that use the SP 2010 Client Object Model to do the SP functionality you require. You could also do a combination of HTML/jQuery to access your business objects from Web Services.

John